# Retrieving two values for ajaxForm(), using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass both the values using ajaxForm, displaying both the values separately in test.php

```
-------test.php-----------------------------------------

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('#test_form').ajaxForm({
    target:'#result',

    success:function() {
        $('#result').show();
    }
});


</script>



<form id="test_form" method="" action="test1.php">
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="sub_value">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

-------test1.php---------------------------------------


<?
$t="test value";
$u="test value 1";

?>
```

Comment: I want to display values of $u and $t on test.php

Answer (score 0):

```
-------test1.php---------------------------------------
<?
$t="test value";
$u="test value 1";

// output the result...
echo "$t $u";
?>
```

This will end up displaying both your values in your target div...

If you want to handle the bits of data independently then try this...

```
<?
$result['u'] = 'test 1';
$result['t'] = 'test 2';
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Update your javascript to handle the returned array any way you like...

Comment: If you want to get 2 different values back from 1 call, and do different things with them, then you will probably be better off returning the data in json format and then changing your javascript to handle it how you want.